# fgets returning NULL even though file is not empty

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

I have the following code:

```
void readFile(FILE* fp)
{
    int lines = 4;
    char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        if(fgets(line, 100, fp)!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n FGETS NOT NULL \n");
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
    }
    free(line);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("t.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
       printf("Error.\n");
       exit(0);
    }
    readFile(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The file I'm passing into the function contains:

```
add $s0 $s1 $s2
sub $s2 $s3 $s6
addi $s2 $s3 15
haltSim
```

I'm not getting any output. For some reason, fgets always returns NULL. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did `fopen("t.txt", "r");` succeed or fail? How do you know? (hint: `if (fp == NULL) { perror ("fopen-t.txt"); return 1; }` -- then `readFile(fp);`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I forgot to the include the check when writing the code in here. Edited. No error, as far I can tell.

Comment: OK, that was what was sticking out like a sore-thumb. Other than better to use a fixed buffer (e.g. `char line[100];` rather than allocating), there is nothing glaring in your use of `fgets`. Using your code and your data file, I get `"FGETS NOT NULL\nadd $s0 $s1 $s2...."`.

Comment: `char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` is better written as `char *line = malloc(100);`. The cast is unnecessary (and can mask errors in some circumstances), and `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. Or just `char line[100;`.

Comment: After adding `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` to the top, I can't reproduce the problem. Your actual code must have at least the first; otherwise the name `FILE` would not be recognized. Please include your complete code (copy-and-pasted) in the question.

Comment: In a comment on one of the answers, you wrote: "the code is part of a much smaller [larger?] project (the readFile actually parses the input and creates a struct from it, but I commented out that part while debugging, included the printf statements). What's weird is whenever I try to run the program with just the main and readFile, it works fine; but running them while part of the bigger project results in no output." So the program in the question doesn't exhibit the problem -- **and you didn't tell us that**. The problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve]. Voting to close.

Comment: Is there any chance that your data file has CRLF line endings and this is somehow screwing things up?  The CR would move the write position to the start of a line.  I'm not entirely convinced it would explain the apparent absence of output, but funnier things have been known.  Have you fed the standard output of your program through a hex dump program (`xxd -g 1` for example)?  Are you sure there isn't an empty file `t.txt` in the current directory from where the program is run?

Comment: Incidentally, if you don't use either `argc` or `argv`, a better signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.  But it would be better to take the file name as an argument (so you'd use `argc` and `argv` after all), rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I tried it with CRLF endings on the input file. It didn't reproduce the problem described in the question. (`fgets` would simply read a line containing a `'\r'` character; it wouldn't return `NULL`.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINES 4
#define MAXLEN 100

void readFile(FILE* fp)
{
    char line[MAXLEN];
    int n = 0;
    while ((fgets(line, MAXLEN, fp)) && n < MAXLINES) {
      printf("n: %d, %s\n", n, line);
      ++n;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* fp;
    if (argc < 2) {
      printf ("USAGE: myprog <filename>\n");
      return 1;
    }
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
      perror("File open error");
      return 1;
    }
    readFile(fp);
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not at all sure what's wrong with your original version - it might be helpful to step through the debugger, if you're interested.

But a few points:

1. You don't want "magic numbers" like 4, or 100
2. If you don't need to malloc() - then don't.  Just declare an array.
3. If you're reading a file in a loop - it's probably better to bound the loop with your actual I/O (and perhaps add a secondary check like "less than MAXLINES").
4. "return" from main is preferred over "exit()", when possible.

Comment: I just tried my code on a linux distro and it seems to be working fine. Trying the same code using Cygwin results in no output. Might it have to do with the fact I'm using Cygwin?

Comment: @Rish 1) Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` to insure output.  2) Add some `printf("Hello World\n")` even if no  lines  print.

Comment: Hi - I can't imagine running in a Cygwin command prompt would necessarily make a difference.  There's "something else" going on here.  Q: What's your compiler?  Q: The snippet above needs an `#include <stdio.h>` to compile.  Is there anything else missing from the snippet you posted?  Q: Have you single-stepped using a debugger?  Q: Does *EVERY* line *ALWAYS* return "NULL"?  Q: What happens if you create a different file (e.g. with Windows "Notepad")?

Comment: @paulsm4 the code is part of a much smaller project (the readFile actually parses the input and creates a struct from it, but I commented out that part while debugging, included the printf statements). What's weird is whenever I try to run the program with just the main and readFile, it works fine; but running them while part of the bigger project results in no output. (I don't think there's anything interfering with the code as I commented majority of the code out to debug). 1) gcc 2) Yes, all headers are included 3) Every line returns a NULL 4) No change, using different editors or environs.

Comment: @Rish: I just tried your program on Cygwin and didn't reproduce the problem. I assume you mean it's part of a much *larger* project.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to paulsm4's answer, I would go one step further and avoid hardcoding the filename. (don't use *magic numbers* or hardcode filenames)

There is no need for `malloc` and you will want to read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Instead using a fixed buffer is fine (but don't SKIMP).

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* don't SKIMP on buffer size */

void readFile (FILE* fp)
{
    char line[MAXC];

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n FGETS NOT NULL \n");
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* read file given as argv[1] or stdin if no argument given.
     * don't hardcode filenames
     */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    readFile(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

(**Remember** `fgets` reads and includes the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer it fills, so you may want to replace `printf("%s\n", line);` with `printf ("%s", line);` or simply `fputs (line, stdout);`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgetsnull t.txt

 FGETS NOT NULL
add $s0 $s1 $s2


 FGETS NOT NULL
sub $s2 $s3 $s6


 FGETS NOT NULL
addi $s2 $s3 15


 FGETS NOT NULL
haltSim
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Huh.. so I just tried this on a linux distro and it seems to be working fine. Trying the same code using Cygwin results in no output. Might it have to do with the fact I'm using Cygwin?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, (even with different line endings `CRLF` verses `LF`). Though that is the only thing I can think of that would be different between the systems. Cygwin should behave the same on windows as the code does on Linux (that's the purpose of standards) Is it possible that `"t.txt"` isn't seen in the Cygwin environment? The reason I have Linux, MinGW on windows and VS and the code behaves exactly the same regardless.

Comment: The code is part of a much smaller project (the readFile actually parses the input and creates a struct from it, but I commented out that part while debugging, included the printf statements). What's weird is whenever I try to run the program with just the main and readFile, it works fine; but running them while part of the bigger project results in no output. (I don't think there's anything interfering with the code as I commented majority of the code out to debug).

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere... You are likely experiencing *Undefined Behavior* due to your use of another stack variable or using an unallocated pointer either within you read function or main that is causing the strange behavior. Edit and post the actual code and I'll bet I can pick it out `:)`